# Compare elements in list and remove if some properties are the same

Tags: java, collections, traversal

I have an array list of objects which contains eg:

- Name
- Address
- Phone
- Many other properties...

I wish to remove some objects in this list, if some of the properties has the same value as other objects in the array list. I need to loop though the whole list and see if the Name, Address and Phone already exists in this list. I can not do a simple:

```
for (...)
if (!newlist.contains(element)) { newlist.add(element); }
```

As I only need to check specific properties are the same before adding the `element` to a new list.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?  Your question seems to pretty much write out exactly what you would need to do in code, i.e. loop through the list, check the attributes of each of the objects within it and remove if necessary.

Comment: Yes, I've tried doing multiple loops and compare the element in one loop to the other. But I can not modify the collection in the iteration.

Comment: Or create a `Set` out of your `List`, that will automatically remove duplicates. And oh, your class needs to be comparable for that.

Comment: Use an iterator not a for loop if you want to modify it.

Comment: Sorry for trying to explain my problem. I have a list. I wish to compare some of the object properties to the same properties in the other objects in the list. If they dont exist I wish to add the object to a new list.

Answer (score 3):

How about using Set with a custom Comparator ? Have your object class implement Comparable. In the compare method you can then write your test to match the objects exactly how you need it.

Comment: -1 Set idea is nice, however implement comparable part is wrong, point is equals method.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Key Class let us say **Employee.java** with below code.

```
package com.innovation;


public class Employee {
private String name;
private String address;
private String phone;

public Employee() {
    super();
}

public Employee(String name, String address, String phone) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((address == null) ? 0 : address.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((phone == null) ? 0 : phone.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;
    if (address == null) {
        if (other.address != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!address.equals(other.address))
        return false;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    if (phone == null) {
        if (other.phone != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!phone.equals(other.phone))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [name=" + name + ", address=" + address + ", phone="
            + phone + "]";
}



}
```

Now create a Client class where you want to apply your logic let us assume a class containing main method say **Client.java**

```
package com.innovation;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Set<Employee> empSet = new HashSet<Employee>(populateList());

        for (Employee employee : empSet)
        {
            System.out.println(employee);
        }

    }   

    public static List<Employee> populateList()
    {
        List<Employee> lsts = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        lsts.add(new Employee("rais","gurgaon","123456"));
        lsts.add(new Employee("alam","Delhi","123685"));
        lsts.add(new Employee("shyam","Mumbai","1257456"));
        lsts.add(new Employee("ramesh","Ahmadabad","196356"));
        lsts.add(new Employee("rais","gurgaon","123456"));
        lsts.add(new Employee("rais","gurgaon","123456"));
        lsts.add(new Employee("rais","gurgaon","123456"));


        return lsts;

    }

}
```

You will see below out put. it is clearly visible that duplicate entry present in list is removed in set. it all magic of good implementation of equals and hashcode method.

```
Employee [name=rais, address=gurgaon, phone=123456]
Employee [name=ramesh, address=Ahmadabad, phone=196356]
Employee [name=alam, address=Delhi, phone=123685]
Employee [name=shyam, address=Mumbai, phone=1257456]
```

Comment: didn't read your codes through, made a duplicated answer. deleted and +1 yours